# How to set Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules for specific email domain and allow read write to multiple parent nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How to set security rules for Firebase realtime database structure as below:

```
users: {
...
...
...
},
books: {
...
...
...
},
sales: {
...
...
...
}
```

Condition: Firebase auth is set to email/password and only user logged-in with emails ending with domain [mydomain.co.in] must be able to read or write to parent node. Without using custom claims.

Adding below security rules is applied/working only for the the first parent node [users] and not to all, what is a miss here?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)",
      ".write": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)",
      ".indexOn": "name"
    },
      
    "books": {
      ".read": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)",
      ".write": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)",
      ".indexOn": "title"
    },
    "sales": {
      ".read": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)",
      ".write": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)",
      ".indexOn": "price"
    },
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below enclosed within uid field?
Reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database

same code works with auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)

```
    {
   "rules":{
    ".read": "false",
    ".write": "false",
      "users":{
         "$uid":{
            ".read":" auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.co.in')",
            ".write":" auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.co.in')",
            ".indexOn":"name"
         }
      },
      "books":{
         "$uid":{
            ".read":" auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.co.in')",
            ".write":" auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.co.in')",
            ".indexOn":"title"
         }
      },
      "sales":{
         "$uid":{
            ".read":" auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.co.in')",
            ".write":" auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.co.in')",
            ".indexOn":"price"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Auth Token payload

```
{
  "token":{
     "email": "test@mydomain.co.in"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ERROR Error: permission_denied at /books: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Comment: ERROR Error: permission_denied at /sales: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Comment: Sorry, Give a try at your end not working for me with above code. or try the firebase rules simulator.

Comment: For "remove top level read & write rules" that was needed to block full access to hackers

Comment: same code works with auth.token.email.matches(/.*@mydomain.co.in$/)